# ¿Por qué una hoja html no me esta tomando los estilos CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Hola estoy realizando una pagina web con php, todo me estaba funcionando perfecto hasta que cree una nueva pagina para la interfaz de usuario del login.
Tengo un archivo que se llama index.css y desde allí estoy dándole estilo a las diferentes paginas que he estado creando, el problema que tengo radica cuando desde index.css le doy estilos a las etiquetas que están en mi pagina login.php, no se aplican todos los estilos, según vi en inspeccionar solo se están aplicando los estilos:

```
.main-content{
    margin-top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Sen', sans-serif;
}
```

No se me están aplicando los siguientes estilos:

```
form{
    max-width: 460px;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 40px auto;
}
form h3{
    margin: 5px 0;
}
form input{
    padding: 7px 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 22px);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
form button{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    width: calc(100%);
    background: var(--main-blue);
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
}
form p{
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: var(--main-red);
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Este es el código de mi login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sistema E-Commerce</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sen&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo-place"><a href="index.php"><img src="assets/logo.png"></a></div>
    </header>
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="content-page">
            <form action="servicios/login.php" method="POST" >
                <h3>Iniciar sesión</h3>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emausu" placeholder="Correo"  required="true">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pasusu" placeholder="Contraseña" required="true">
                <?php
                    if (isset($_GET['e'])) {
                        switch ($_GET['e']) {
                            case '1':
                                echo '<p>Error de conexión</p>';
                                break;  
                            case '2':
                                echo '<p>Email inválido</p>';
                                break;  
                            case '3':
                                echo '<p>Contraseña incorrecta</p>';
                                break;                          
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="prueba">Ingresar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Y este es el index.css completo

```
:root{
    --main-header-color:linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(245, 15, 16),#EF5962);
    --main-blue:#3483FA;
    --main-red:rgb(245, 15, 16);
}
body,html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
header{
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    line-height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    background: var(--main-header-color);
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    
}
form{
    max-width: 460px;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 40px auto;
}
form h3{
    margin: 5px 0;
}
form input{
    padding: 7px 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 22px);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
form button{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    width: calc(100%);
    background: var(--main-blue);
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
}
form p{
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: var(--main-red);
    font-size: 14px;
}
.logo-place{
    width: 70px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    
}
.logo-place img{
    width: 100%;

}
.search-place{
    width: calc(100% - 400px);
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px 20px;  

}
input{
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width: calc(100% - 62px);
    font-family: 'Sen', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
    
}
input:placeholder{
    color: #ccc;
}
.search-place input{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width: calc(100% - 62px);
    font-family: 'Sen', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
}
.search-place input:placeholder{
    color: #ccc;
}
.btn-main{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    border-style: none;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn-search{
    width: 40px;
    color: #333;
}
.options-place{
    width: 250px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    
    
}
.item-option{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: 'Sen', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    
}
.item-option p{
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
    
}
.main-content{
    margin-top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Sen', sans-serif;
}
.content-page{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    max-width: 1180px;
}
.content-page section{
    display: flex;
    background: #fff;
}
.part1{
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc(60% - 20px);
}
.part2{
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc(40% - 20px);
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.part1 img{
    width: 100%;
}
.part2 *{
    margin: 10px 0;
    font-family: 'Sen', sans-serif;
}
.part2 h2{
    color: #333;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.part2 h1{
    color: var(--main-red);
    font-size: 45px;
}
.part2 h1 span{
    color: var(--main-red);
    font-size: 30px;
}
.part2 h3{
    color: #333;
    font-weight: normal;
}
button{
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #3483FA;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.part2 button{
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #3483FA;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.part2 #quantity-input{
    width: 50px;
}

.title-section{
    padding: 10px 0; 
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #666;
    font-family: 'Sen', sans-serif;
}
.products-list{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.product-box{
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc(100%/5 - 20px);
}
.product-box a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.product{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 3px #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Sen', sans-serif;
}
.product img{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.detail-title{
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #333;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    height: 35px;
}
.detail-description{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    padding: 5px;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    height: 34px;
}
.detail-price{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: var(--main-red);
    padding: 5px;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
.detail-price span{
    font-size: 15px;
}
a{
    color: #fff;
}
.body-pedidos{
    width: 100%;
}
.item-pedido{
    display: flex;
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: #fff;
}
.pedido-img{
    width: 200px;
}
.pedido-img img{
    width: 100%;
}
.pedido-detalle{
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 220px);
}
.pedido-detalle h3,
.pedido-detalle p{
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.ipt-procom{
    width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.p-line{
    display: flex;
}
.p-line div{
    width: 150px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.metodo-pago{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
input[type="radio"]{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
}
.metodo-pago label{
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
.content-page h4{
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

PD: Algo que note es que si le aplico estilos desde el mismo html

```
<style type="text/css">
(ESTILOS)
</style>
```

Si se aplican y también otra solución que encontré es que crear un archivo por ejemplo login.css
y allí pegar los estilos que quiero y linkearlo en mi login.php en el head, pero quiero saber porque no me funciona haciéndolo desde el index.css.

Comment: Me gustaría saber la raíz donde se encuentran tus hojas de estilos. Tal vez sea un error de rutas.

Comment: Mi proyecto esta en una carpeta que se llama Ecommerce y dentro de esta carpeta hay otras carpetas, por ejemplo mi index.css esta dentro de la carpeta CSS, y mi login.php esta en la carpeta Ecommerce, es decir, no esta dentro de otra carpeta. Pero nose si esto genere problema, ya que mis otras paginas están al mismo nivel que login.php y si me funcionan correctamente.

Comment: Vete a tu pagina web, justo en la pagina donde no funcionan tus estilos css y oprime `Ctrl + Shift + I` Una vez que se habrá la **Herramienta de desarrollador**, dirígete al apartado que se llama `Network` y allí marca la casilla que se llama **Disable Cache** y luego refresca la pagina web. Nota: si la casilla `Disable cache` ya esta activada, desmárcala, refresca la pagina y vuelve a marcarla y vuelve a refrescar la pagina. Me deja saber cualquier cosa.

Comment: me funcionó muchas gracias. ¿Como evito tener que estar activando disable cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo visto, tu problema es un asunto relacionado con la **Cache** del navegador. Lo que tienes que hacer es: vete a tu pagina web, justo en la pagina donde no funcionan tus estilos css y oprime `Ctrl + Shift + I`. Una vez que se habrá la **Herramienta de desarrollador**, dirígete al apartado que se llama **Network** y allí marca la casilla que se llama `Disable Cache` y luego refresca la pagina web. **Nota:** si la casilla `Disable cache` ya esta activada, **desmárcala**, refresca la pagina y vuelve a marcarla y vuelve a refrescar la pagina.

Me imagino que debes de estar usando **Google Chrome** ya que este es un problema que suele suceder mucho en este navegador.

### ¿Qué puedes hacer para que esto no suceda y evitar refrescar siempre la Cache?

- Una opción que no te recomiendo mucho es: escribirle a tus reglas de
  estilos **CSS** la propiedad `important` a todas tus reglas, de esa
  manera le estarás diciendo al navegador que esos estilos son
  importantes y que tiene que reflejarlos. Un ejemplo seria:

```css
p {
  height: 10rem important;
  color: #000 important;
  padding: 10px important;
}
```

- Otra cosa que puedes hacer, y sí te la recomiendo, es: usar el
  navegador **Mozilla Firefox** para diseñar tus plantillas en CSS, ya
  que a diferencia de **Google Chrome**, mozilla no suele almacenar
  nada en Cache y tiende a presentar los cambios en la página sin
  problemas.
- Otra cosa que puedes hacer, si quieres usar **Google Chrome** por X
  razón. Es que instales el editor de Código: **Visual Studio Code**, y
  dentro de este editor, instales un servidor virtual llamado: **Live Server** en el que puedes diseñar tus plantillas y ver los cambios en
  tiempo real, sin problemas de cache. Puedes buscar un tutorial en YouTube donde te enseñarán todo paso a paso.

Existen mil formas de solucionar el tema de las cache, pero yo solo quise hablarte de las más importantes, las que yo suelo usar a la hora de diseñar mis plantillas.

Estaré pendiente a tu respuesta, un cordial saludo.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias amigo